# How can i hide/show images while scrolling in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to iOS programming and i want to learn something about UITableView.

I have some images in UITableViewCell. I want to hide my images when scrolling start then i want to show them when scrolling stop.

How can i do that ? 
Is there a method or something else about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, thus you can in your tableView delegate receive
 UIScrollViewDelegate callbacks.

Implement the delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

which tells the delegate when the scroll view is about to start scrolling the content.

and

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

which tells the delegate when the user finishes scrolling the content.

Read the [ScrollViewDelegate Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a big deal you simply need to implement scrollview delegated methodes to know when scrolling stops ,Then set a bool value and reload the table and on basis of bool value you can  show and hide the images.When scrolling starts set bool to NO.